# Partial correlation in R without correlating everything

Tags: r

I need help figuring out how to write the R code for a partial correlation, I'm still fairly new to R. I have a dataset with 22 columns of interval data. I'm trying to run a partial correlation of columns 19:22 with columns 2:18, controlling for/partialling out column 1. I've used the following code:

```
par.r=partial.r(dataset, c(2:22), c(1))
```

The problem is that this gives me everything correlated together, which isn't what I'm looking for. If this was a standard correlation I would use the below code:

```
normal.correlation = corr.test(dataset[,c(2:18)],[,c(19:22)], method="spearman")
```

My question is how do I run a partial correlation with my variables without correlating everything? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is not partial correlation. This is correlation between subsets.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to do a correlation between subsets while partialling out/controlling for one variable?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because of a timing issue that you don't want to correlate everything? If not then you could use the following to extract the relevant part of the (full) partial correlation matrix

```
par.r=partial.r(dataset, c(2:22), c(1))
par[1:17,18:21]
```